# RenderThread vs UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

From the Android Threads [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads):

> you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread

So I believe that everything on the screen is rendered by the **UI thread**. But in Android Lollipop they have [introduced](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#Material) a **RenderThread**:

> A new system-managed processing thread called RenderThread keeps animations smooth even when there are delays in the main UI thread

How does it work? Does the **RenderThread** use the **UI thread** to render animations (Views with new properties) on the screen? If so, why doesn't it block the **UI thread**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `RenderThread` depends on the `UI Thread` but it does run in parallel along with the last mentioned one.

Its main job is to run expensive computation on the `GPU` in order to empty the heavy load of the `UI Thread`.

---

> How does it work?

Basically, the `UI Thread` acts as a job dispatcher. It prepares a pipeline of commands to be executed on the `RenderThread`.

The `GPU` doesn't know what an animation is; it can only understand basic commands, e.g:

- `translation(x,y,z)`
- `rotate(x,y)`

or basic drawing utilities:

- `drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint)`
- `drawRoundRect(left, top, right, bottom, cornerRadiusX, cornerRadiusY, paint)`

Combined together they form the complex animation you see on the screen.

> Does the RenderThread use the UI thread to render animations (Views with new properties) on the screen?

No, it runs asynchronously

> If so, why doesn't it block the UI thread?

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html) explain that the rendering is performed in two phases:

1. `View#draw` -> `UI Thread`
2. `DrawFrame` -> `RenderThread`, which performs work based on the `View#draw` phase.

On a lower level, when using hardware acceleration, the deferred `rendering` is executed by a  [DisplayListCanvas](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/DisplayListCanvas.java).

In this `Canvas` implementation you can find the aforementioned drawing commands, such as `drawCircle`.

As such, the `DisplayListCanvas` is also the drawing target of the [RenderNodeAnimator](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/RenderNodeAnimator.java), which runs the basic animation commands (`translate`, `scale`, `alpha`, ...).

Answer (score 3):

**Render thread** as it name explains just do the rendering *`onDraw()`*, **UI Thread** do `onMeasure()`, `onLayout()`, etc... 
the concept of that separation  is to do the hard work of measuring and calculating the other things without blocking the rendering that leads to smooth **fps**

watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HtTL_RO2wI)