# Why can't UI thread and Render thread run at the same time?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am a mediocore android developer for years. I like android but there's a big problem; frame drops. Even the most powerful ones can stutter so frequently while IOS devices can run at constant 60fps. I just can't understand why. I want to know it. So first thing i did was watching an I/O presentation about performance. And i didn't really understand one thing. Why can't ui and render thread run at the same time ? Yeah i know the basics like render thread can't know what to render while ui thread is doing it's thing but why can't render thread render the frame before? You can see the video here:
https://youtu.be/9HtTL_RO2wI?t=491
And here's a diagram what am i asking for:
[image: Dıagram]

You get the idea. I don't know about low level things about android, can anyone explain this like i'm five.

Comment: The **RenderThread** *depends* on the **UI Thread** but it does run in ***parallel*** (**most** phones are *single* **CPU** processor, *single* **GPU** processor, I *think* and use standard time-slice).
It's main job is to run *expensive computation* on the **GPU** in order to empty the heavy load of the **UI** Thread. see [RenderThread vs UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618444/renderthread-vs-ui-thread).

Answer (score 1):

Your process' main thread is responsible for the rendering of the frames that will be presented to the user, so you should keep the code running there as fast and light as possible. If you have to do some heavy processing or access any IO (network, sdcard, etc) that may impact on the fluidity of the application since the thread may be waiting for a response.

As a good practice you should start that IO access/heavy processing on another thread to run in background and let the system decide the priority to run it, if necessary is recommended to present some feedback to the user like a ProgressBar or something to indicate that something is being processed.

Also, the Render Thread need to know what to render before it does it, so the UI Thread have to process which information the app would like to present to the user.

Comment: Yeah i now that but my question was  different. Can't render thread render the previous frame instead of waiting for current ui thread finishes it's job? Can't we just store the data of previous ui thread and render it as i showed in diagram?

Comment: There is no reason to do so, because if a frame is skipped the last frame isn't removed from the screen it will just take another cycle to update it. You can visualize this during an ANR even though the thread is blocked an the UI stopped responding the last frame remain stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

As @JonGoodwin points out, they both run in parallel, but usually in two cores of the same processor, as nowadays phones have at least two cores. Both threads are run in CPU, where RenderThread sends rendering commands to the GPU. Notice that this is true since API 21 (RenderThread is what enables things like ripple effect).

The problem, though, is what @LucianoFerruzzi points out: usually poor code that does too many things in the UI thread (RenderThread is not accessible, at least not with standard mechanisms).

Also, see the following episode of [Android Developers Backstage](https://androidbackstage.blogspot.com): [Episode 74: Graphics](https://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2017/08/episode-74-graphics.html)